# Accessing file in a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a web app consisting of an MVC project (starting UI) and few class library projects

Please consider this scenario.. Logistics.sln containing

```
Proj1 - Logistics.UI (MVC)
           Content
           Images
           Views
           Controllers
           web.config
Proj2 - Logistics.Domain (class library)
Proj3 - Logistics.Data (class library)
Proj4 - Logistics.Services (class library)
          SomeRandomClass.cs
          somefile.txt
```

Logistics.Services project has a class called SomeRandomClass. How can I access somefile.txt in a method of that class?

Tried using HostingEnvironment.MapPath but it points to Logistics.UI project.

Then tried the following but this also points to UI projects folder path

```
var appDomain = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
var basePath = appDomain.RelativeSearchPath ?? appDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Comment: How do you know `somefile.txt` is included in the build output? If it isn't included somehow (e.g. as an embedded resource stream, `*.resx` file, or copy-to-build-output) then it won't be available. .NET is not like PHP where the source files are simply copied to the running environment.

Comment: In properties of somefile.txt, I set Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always

Comment: The path you need has nothing to do with your poject structure in Visual Studio. You have to find out, where the file is installed when you publish your application.

Comment: But do you copy the file from `Logistics.Services\bin\{Configuration}` to your `Logistics.UI\bin\` directory? (or `Logistics.UI\bin\{Configuration}` in ASP.NET Core)